# scrollview with a button that expands when the button is tapped in ios

Tags: ios, button, scrollview

I am new to IOS development, i would like to ask how i could make a scrollview with some buttons in it aligned horizontally, in which when you tab on one of the buttons the scrollview expand and displays infor data, and when you tab it again it contract or goes to the normal size again). Something like when you open grouped apps on the iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action of your `UIButton` try to change the `UIScrollView`'s frame.